# What functionalities will not available in SharePoint 2010 web app. when backward compatibility is on (V3 mode)?

Tags: 2010

I have attached my MOSS 2007 content DB to SPS 2010 farm with backward compatibility (v3) also copied my custom theme. it is working fine.

i need to know beside UI related features like, ribbon and ajax etc. what functional level features will not be available for my V3 web app.? for example;

1. Does my document library will support document-set feature?
2. Can I use SPD 2010 with my v3 web app?
3. Will I be able to configure custom workflows in SPD (which were not possible in 2007) and attach to my document libraries in V3 web app? etc.

i think was able to clarify the question.

thanks & regards,

Mohsin

Answer (score 1):

V3 master pages are just that. They utilize the 2007 masterpages and css.  The underlying functionality never changes.  You may not be able to access those features via UI though.  SPD funtions including workflows are available.